# Quais as diferenças práticas na portabilidade de código C e C++?

Tags: c, c++, portabilidade

Tenho lido alguns códigos open-source em C ultimamente e percebi que muitos deles se tornam bastante complexos e com bastante `#ifdef` a fim de tornar o código o mais portável possível entre várias plataformas e *NIX diferentes. Alguns oferecem suporte até mesmo a bibliotecas diferentes em um mesmo programa.

Gostaria de questionar se na prática, o C++ pode sobrepor esse tipo de problema de portabilidade. Um exemplo de código para ter o comando `mkdir` de forma portável:

```
// Try to bring in unistd.h if possible
#if !defined(__TURBOC__) && !defined(_MSC_VER)
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

// Bring in direct.h if we need to; sometimes mkdir/rmdir is defined here
#if defined(__WATCOMC__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
#include <direct.h>
#endif

// Fill in S_ISDIR
#if !defined(_POSIX_VERSION) && !defined(S_ISDIR)
#define S_ISDIR(m) (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR)
#endif

#if defined(__TURBOC__) || defined(__WATCOMC__) || defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
//
// Already have a single-argument mkdir()
//
#else
//
// Provide a single-argument mkdir()
//
#define mkdir(a) mkdir(a, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO)
#endif
```

Código retirado de common.h do pacote cmdpack (apt-get install cmdpack em sistemas Debian-like)

Na prática, o C++ consegue ser mais portável? Entendo que a biblioteca padrão do C++ deveria oferecer todos os recursos necessários (considerando C++11) para programar em qualquer plataforma, não sendo necessário este tipo de código. Qual a real intenção do programador em fazer este tipo de código e principalmente, como o C++ resolve (ou tenta resolver) este tipo de situação?

Comment: E você tem lido códigos em C++ e não encontra a mesma estrutura? Já pensou se isto é apenas uma questão de estilo?

Comment: Na verdade leio poucos códigos em C++, mas fiquei bastante intrigado em porque fizeram este tipo de #if visto que as primeiras versões não portaveis do código não tinham nada disso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pré-processador

É assim que se resolve as partes diferentes para cada plataforma. Não sei o quanto conhece as linguagens, mas isto faz parte do pré-processador.

Essas diretivas do pré-processador ajudam traduzir o código antes mesmo da compilação do programa, portanto tudo que está em um `#if` (que não faz parte da construção do programa) daquela plataforma simplesmente é ignorado até mesmo pelo compilador. Esta tradução é uma forma simples de modificação do código. Embora faça parte do processo de construção do programa e seja feito pelo compilador não é exatamente o processo de compilação em si que lida com isto. Daí existem até algumas críticas que sua utilização pode trazer problemas já que essa tradução é "burra", não entende muito o que está fazendo. Mas ela funciona bem quando o programador sabe usar corretamente e não existe uma solução universalmente melhor.

Isto torna a compilação mais rápida (tem menos código para compilar efetivamente), e evidentemente o código de máquina gerado fica menor e mais rápido, afinal ele não precisa decidir em tempo de execução se aquilo é relevante para aquela plataforma ou não.

Provavelmente a alternativa seria resolver isto em tempo de execução de alguma forma. Não ficará bom para a maioria dos programas. No mínimo o programa será maior sem necessidade, afinal tem coisas nele que jamais serão usadas naquela plataforma em que ele está rodando (lembre-se que um programa gerado para uma plataforma não roda em outra). Dependendo da técnica usada para selecionar qual código executar pode até ficar mais lento (teoricamente, porque ninguém vai chegar neste ponto).

Isto vale para C e para C++. C++ essencialmente é o C com alguns recursos a mais (vou deixar de lado alguns detalhes irrelevantes para esta pergunta). Estes recursos podem diminuir bastante a necessidade de uso do pré-processador mas neste caso de selecionar o código específico de plataforma não tem nada melhor.

Claro, você não sabe disto, mas sua pergunta não parece fazer muito sentido. Um dos motivos que talvez você ache isto é que não tem muita experiência com ambas então entenda:

- Códigos podem ser mais ou menos portáveis.

  C++ tem mais recursos. Por isto tem mais possibilidades deles serem mal usados dificultando a portabilidade. Mas isto é problema do código, do programador, não da linguagem.
- Linguagens no máximo podem ter mais ou menos facilidades para separar códigos para diferentes plataformas (não é o caso de C++ sobre C).

  Em termos de ter mais recursos que ajudem a portabilidade, mesmo os que vão além do pré-processador, se tem algo a mais, é muito pouco. Teria que fazer um uso criativo de algumas coisas. Muitas vezes vai trazer mais problemas do que benefícios.

  É possível usar *templates*, por exemplo, mas dificilmente trará alguma vantagem real. Não vejo isto sendo usado nos códigos que costumo ler (que é diferente de não existir).
- As implementações de uma linguagem podem atender mais ou menos plataformas.

  Na prática costuma-se dizer que C++ é ligeiramente menos portável porque não há boas implementações para todas as plataformas. Mas há controvérsias quanto a isso ser uma verdade absoluta.
- Biblioteca é algo diferente da linguagem

  O que certamente o C++ tem a mais **por padrão**, principalmente o C++11, C++14, C++17, etc., são bibliotecas que já tratam as diferentes plataformas para você. Mas não é um recurso da linguagem. Aí você vai ver como estas bibliotecas foram escritas e provavelmente vai achar um monte de `#if` lá. Ou seja, a vantagem é que alguém já fez para você.

  Claro que em C tem bibliotecas que tratam as diferenças de plataforma e facilitam a vida do programador, mas pouca coisa está na biblioteca que é considerada como padrão da linguagem.

Alguém pode vir aqui e responder que faz muita diferença para a portabilidade usar C ou C++. Isto pode ocorrer porque desconheço alguma técnica pouco conhecida ou porque algumas pessoas gostam tanto de usar determinado recurso que preferem ele mais do que qualquer outro. Tem gente que tem tanto ódio ao uso do pré-processador que pode preferir todas as dificuldades do *template*, para ela será mais fácil ([a melhor ferramenta é aquela que você sabe e se dá bem](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/09/01.html)).

Ambas tem um outro problema que dificulta a portabilidade entre versões da linguagem ou bibliotecas ou mesmo implementações (compiladores). Provavelmente o C++ sofre mais com isto, mas acredito que não é bem o que você está perguntando.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente oque eu pretendia perguntar. Fique a vontade para editar a pergunta caso ache necessário.